# How to use selenium to click on X/Y coordinates inorder to click on flash buttons

Tags: python, selenium

I know actions chain have click element at x y but unsure how to keep track of it. Is there a simple way to click an element at x y and also keep track of. I need it to click on flash

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.google.ca/") 
driver.click(250,250)
```

For example just click somewhere at x 250, y 250.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by *how to keep track of it*, but Selenium provides action chains for clicking at arbitrary locations on the page. If the click does not cause a page transition or the element to be hidden, etc., you can get a handle to the object after doing the action chain by using `switch_to.active_element`. Perhaps that's what you wanted for keeping track?

Comment: This cannot work there is no click function in webdriver.